# How to trigger check all checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclick, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how to trigger a link button to trigger and change all checkboxes to checked when clicked upon. When I click the button, it will bring up the alert message, but not triggering the checkboxes. I've tried some answers listed in this site, but it doesn't work. I recreated the problem with a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1k6r5j4/).

**HTML:**

```
<h3><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="checkAll">Check</a> All</h3>
<hr/>
<input class="categories" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Math" checked>Math<br/>
<input class="categories" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Science" checked>Science<br/>
<input class="categories" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Reading" checked>Reading
```

**JS:**

```
$('#checkAll').click(function()
{
  alert("checkAll was clicked!");
  console.log("Checkboxes has been refilled!");
  $(':checkbox.categories').prop('checked', $(this).checked); // re-check all checkboxes
  //$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because `this` will refer to the `a` element and the jQuery object containing that element has no `checked` property. Instead, just set it to `true`:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(':checkbox.categories').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7f9oyv6z/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! :)